# Rodapé está se repetindo quando carrego a PartialView no change da Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alterei a pergunta para ficar mais clara, estava suja e agora compreendi melhor o problema.
Quando abro a lista, tenho um botão Detalhes. Ao clicar nesse botão, me abre a tela de detalhes e nessa tela uma DropDownList. Acontece é que quando eu clicar na DropDown, é disparado uma jquery que deveria repopular o grid, já com o novo id e etc. Esse repopular é uma PartialView que deveria ser carregada e não está sendo, apenas a view completa e por isso o Rodapé está duplicando. Eu não consigo identificar na Controller quando a chamada é da View e quando é da Jquery. Se conseguisse isso, na controller teria como retornar a View ou a PartialView("nome"). Vou postar a Controller e a jquery.

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Details(AzureDiscountGroupModel model, int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Indice = id;
            var discount = _azureDiscountGroupService.GetAll();
            var list = new List<ResellerListModel>();

            var resellers = _resellerService.QueryAll()
                .Include(r => r.WhiteLabels)
                .ToList();

            foreach(var item in resellers)
            {
                list.Add(CreateListModelFrom(item));
            }

            ViewBag.Desconto = discount.Where(x => x.Id > 0);

            ViewBag.DetailReseller = list.Where(x => x.AzureDiscountGroupId == id).ToList();

           //aqui deveria fazer um if para uma chamada ou outra
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Essa é a minha jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#GrupoDescontos").change(function () {
            var $div = $('#GridPartial');
            $div.html('');
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: '' + $(this).val(),
                type: 'GET',
                    success: function (dados) {
                        $div.html(dados);
                },
                    error: function (erro) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Como faço para identificar uma chamada da View ou se é da Jquery?

Comment: O seguinte, consigo resolver passando um parâmetro a partir da chamada da View Index. Bem, isso funciona, mas a PartialView é apenas uma table e quando eu chamo da jquery, aí já não aparece mais o cabeçalho e a DropDown. Se coloco esses detalhes na PartialView, na primeira carga vindo da Index, aí fica tudo duplicado.

Comment: Resolvi em parte. Passo um parâmetro e removi toda a View. Deixei apenas a div onde seria populada a partialview. Isso resoloveu em perte, o problema é que não consigo fazer mais de uma chamada pela Dropdownlist. Faço uma ok, mas a partir daí não roda mais

Comment: Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Veja como criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) para utilizar na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

certifique-se de que a sua PartialView não está carregando o layout da master.. que pode estar vindo da `_ViewStart`

```
@{
    Layout = null;
} 
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nome
        </th>
        <th>
            Alias
        </th>
        <th>
            WhiteLabel?
        </th>
        <th>
            MPN Id
        ...
```

E simplifique seu código, se não está tratando o erro e apenas fazendo um GET para pegar o conteúdo renderizado, utilize o método `load()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {    
       $("#GrupoDescontos").change(() => {$('#GridPartial').load('' + $(this).val());});                
       $("#GrupoDescontos").val("@ViewBag.Indice");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O que pude deduzir foi isso: `return PartialView()`. Quando a página sobe na primeira vez ok, porém da segunda vez deveria ser apenas isso `return PartialView("DetailsPartial")`, aí sim, apenas a table seria carregada pelo ajax e não toda página, mas como faria isso? Ou faria uma Action só pra isso repetindo o mesmo código exceto no return, isso soa um tanto feio.

Comment: Lenadr, o métdo `load()` não deu certo. Quando faço o segundo change, a partir daí não acontece mais nada

Comment: não acontece mais nada aonde?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira
Na view deixei apenas a div onde seria colocada a PartialView.
Passo uma parâmetro da Index para a Controller e digo se é a primeira passada. Então eu retorno a View ou a PartialView

Comment: Se possível, coloque o código de exemplo